# VHost for flask/mod_wsgi cripples previously working page-serving

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I've managed to get Apache to serve a dynamically generated (by Python/flask/mod_wsgi) "hello world".

I point my browser to http://pipad.org/foo and it displays "hello world".

That's being accomplished by:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/piFlask.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pipad.org

    WSGIDaemonProcess piFlask user=pi group=pi threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /foo /home/pi/web/piFlask/piFlask.wsgi

    <Directory /home/pi/web/piFlask>
        WSGIProcessGroup piFlask
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        # Order deny,allow
        # Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, pages that previously worked now don't function properly.  For example, http://pipad.org/somestatic.html no longer works.

Disabling this new VHost with `sudo a2dissite piFlask;  service apache2 reload` restores the prior correct behaviour.

What is going wrong, and what is the correct way to configure Apache in this situation?

I would like ONLY http://pipad.org/foo to get processed by this VHost.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like ONLY http://pipad.org/foo to get processed by this VHost.

Does that mean you have an another virtual host for this domain as well? If so, try combining both into one.